# How to sum observations based on ID to new aggregated variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm quite new to R, so please be gentle.

I have a dataset that contains multiple columns that are repeated measures for the same individual.
I have and ID-variable that identify the specific individual per row that these measures relate to.

So my data looks something like this

| ID | F329 | T509 | F410 | F209 | B328 | F252 | F259 | F317 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | NA | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | NA | 94 | 29 | 69 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 39 | 59 | 39 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 39 | 59 | 39 |

and so forth...

I want to add together the values in each row if the ID match. I have a huge number on columns so I do not want to name them all.

I want my new dataset to look something like this.

| ID | F329 | T509 | F410 | F209 | B328 | F252 | F259 | F317 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 24 | 28 | 24 | 27 | 376 | 116 | 236 |
| 2 | 12 | 14 | 16 | 18 | 18 | 78 | 118 | 78 |

Suggestions?

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
aggregated_df3 <- aggregated_df2 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("F", "T", "B"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutate creates new columns or modifies existing one. What you are aiming to do is `summarise` each data variable by your grouping variable.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> library(data.table)

> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), ID]
   ID F329 T509 F410 F209 B328 F252 F259 F317
1:  1   20   24   28   24   27  376  116  276
2:  2   12   14   16   18   18   78  118   78
```